# automating browser with phantom.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to automate the browser using phantomjs. I load a page, supply the login credentials and then want to click on the submit button. As the first step I loaded a page, modified the form values and piped the output to a .html file to see if that works. Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  fs.write("/home/phantom/output.html", msg, 'w');
};
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
//page.open('http://google.com', function(status) {
page.open('https://somewebsitehavingaform.com', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementsByName('id').value="id";
        document.getElementsByName('name').value="name";    
        document.getElementsByName('password').value="password";        
        console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    });
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

When i open the output.html, it shows me the form but its empty. I expected id,name and password to be pre-filled. Where i am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `getElementsByName` will return an array. In order to set the value of the first input found with that name, you'd need to choose a specific element in it, i.e. the first:

`getElementsByName('foo')[0].value = 'bar'`

Then, if you change the assignment to use `setAttribute` it seems to work correctly:

```
var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementsByName('id')[0].setAttribute("value", "id");
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].setAttribute("value", "name");
    document.getElementsByName('password')[0].setAttribute("value", "password");
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
});
```

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute),

> Using `setAttribute()` to modify certain attributes, most notably value
>   in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default
>   value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the
>   properties. For example, use `elt.value` instead of
>   `elt.setAttribute('value', val)`.

Though since you're just writing out the resulting HTML to file, I don't think it should cause you a problem in this instance.

Not sure if Phantom JS is now using the QJSEngine internally, but notice [this open ticket](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11304) on their backlog that might be related to the issue you're getting with dot notation:

> [`QJSEngine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qjsengine.html) is a simple wrapper around V8, mainly for use with [`QtQml`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-index.html).
>   Using QJSEngine for the PhantomJS main context might prove to be more
>   malleable/customizable than the current implementation.
>
> Problems:
>
> …
>
> **Automatic property creation when using dot notation does not work with QObjects added to the QJSEngine**

(This suggests that QJSEngine isn't the current implementation in use, but was raised 9 months ago, so not sure if it's been introduced since then, so thought it was worth flagging)